# How to call syscall readahead in Python?

Tags: file, python-3.x, file-io, system-calls

How can I call the [readahead](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) syscall in Python 3?

> readahead() initiates readahead on a file so that subsequent reads
>          from that file will be satisfied from the cache, and not block on
>          disk I/O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) and pull in the system call from `libc`:

```
    import ctypes, os

    # load ourselves, we already have libc
    libc = ctypes.CDLL(None, use_errno=True)

    # XXX - YMMV, ctypes doesn't have c_off_t much less c_off64_t.
    # Assume it's c_longlong, but don't count on that.
    off64_t = ctypes.c_longlong

    def readahead(fobj, offset, count):
        fno = fobj if isinstance(fobj, int) else fobj.fileno()

        code = libc.readahead(
            ctypes.c_int(fno),
            off64_t(offset),
            ctypes.c_size_t(count)
        )
        if code != 0:
            errno = ctypes.get_errno()
            raise OSError(errno, os.strerror(errno))
```